# "SPCR was not declared" when trying to use an rgb matrix on an arduino uno wifi

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have tried several example programs to get an rgb matrix working on my arduino uno wifi.  I feel like an idiot that I can't figure this out, and I've googled tons to no avail.  The errors and code are below.  The problem is that the rgbmatrix library is referencing a var that isn't defined.  Am I missing another library I need to import?  I am a total noob to arduino, but I've developed with netduino and particle photon, fwiw.

Thanks for any help.  I'm trying to build my boy a rocket bookshelf with a cool display, but if I can't get past this, it's going to lose significant cool points :).

```
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp: In member function 'void cRGBMatrix::begin(int)':
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:48:5: error: 'SPCR' was not declared in this scope
     SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR1)|(1<<SPR0); //Enable SPI HW, Master Mode, divide clock by 16    //SPI Bus setup
     ^~~~
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:48:5: note: suggested alternative: 'SCL'
     SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR1)|(1<<SPR0); //Enable SPI HW, Master Mode, divide clock by 16    //SPI Bus setup
     ^~~~
     SCL
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:48:16: error: 'SPE' was not declared in this scope
     SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR1)|(1<<SPR0); //Enable SPI HW, Master Mode, divide clock by 16    //SPI Bus setup
                ^~~
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:48:16: note: suggested alternative: 'PE'
     SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR1)|(1<<SPR0); //Enable SPI HW, Master Mode, divide clock by 16    //SPI Bus setup
                ^~~
                PE
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:48:25: error: 'MSTR' was not declared in this scope
     SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR1)|(1<<SPR0); //Enable SPI HW, Master Mode, divide clock by 16    //SPI Bus setup
                         ^~~~
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:48:25: note: suggested alternative: 'PSTR'
     SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR1)|(1<<SPR0); //Enable SPI HW, Master Mode, divide clock by 16    //SPI Bus setup
                         ^~~~
                         PSTR
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:48:35: error: 'SPR1' was not declared in this scope
     SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR1)|(1<<SPR0); //Enable SPI HW, Master Mode, divide clock by 16    //SPI Bus setup
                                   ^~~~
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:48:35: note: suggested alternative: 'SPI0'
     SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR1)|(1<<SPR0); //Enable SPI HW, Master Mode, divide clock by 16    //SPI Bus setup
                                   ^~~~
                                   SPI0
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:48:45: error: 'SPR0' was not declared in this scope
     SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR1)|(1<<SPR0); //Enable SPI HW, Master Mode, divide clock by 16    //SPI Bus setup
                                             ^~~~
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:48:45: note: suggested alternative: 'SPI0'
     SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR1)|(1<<SPR0); //Enable SPI HW, Master Mode, divide clock by 16    //SPI Bus setup
                                             ^~~~
                                             SPI0
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp: In member function 'char cRGBMatrix::spiTransfer(char)':
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:78:5: error: 'SPDR' was not declared in this scope
     SPDR = value;                    // Start the transmission
     ^~~~
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:78:5: note: suggested alternative: 'SDA'
     SPDR = value;                    // Start the transmission
     ^~~~
     SDA
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:79:14: error: 'SPSR' was not declared in this scope
     while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)))     // Wait for the end of the transmission
              ^~~~
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:79:14: note: suggested alternative: 'SS'
     while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)))     // Wait for the end of the transmission
              ^~~~
              SS
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:79:25: error: 'SPIF' was not declared in this scope
     while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)))     // Wait for the end of the transmission
                         ^~~~
/Users/johnwest/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RGBMatrix/RGBMatrix.cpp:79:25: note: suggested alternative: 'SPI0'
     while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)))     // Wait for the end of the transmission
                         ^~~~
                         SPI0
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Uno WiFi Rev2.

                ^~~
```

```
#include <SPI.h>

#include <RGB.h>
#include <RGBMatrix.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks like code for an Uno not the Uno WiFi.  They use different chips IIRC

Comment: so this is my stupidity, but is there a way to get it to work with the uno wifi?  is it going to be more trouble than it's worth to "convert" this code?

Comment: and as for this code, then, is "SPCR" like a kind of global variable that's only defined if the correct chip is selected?

Comment: SPCR is a particular register on the 328P chip on the UNO that controls the SPI interface.  You will need to look at what those lines actually accomplish and see if you can find the means to accomplish the same thing on the chip you have.   Most likely all you need to do is to find the correct library for your chip.